# Can the selenium download file name be customized in advance?

Tags: python, selenium

I just want to change the name of the downloaded file to the value in my variable. And I use Python.

I can't change the file name after downloading. The default file name is generated according to the current time. I will run multiple driver at the same time, and some files will be downloaded at the same time.

I also can't get the download link in the browser element. The download link is generated by clicking the button. If I can get a link from the file to be downloaded in selenium, my problem can be solved.
Thank you very much for your help.

url:

```
https://ads.google.com/aw/keywordplanner/home?ocid=914430876&euid=626143847&__u=8483461103&uscid=914430876&__c=7080993724&authuser=1&subid=hk-en-et-g-aw-c-home-awhp_xin1_signin%21o2-awhp-hv-01-22
```

Open the URL and click find new keyword

code:

```
import json
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def search_keyword(keyword):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0, 'download.default_directory': f'{os.getcwd()}\\download'}
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    options.add_argument('-ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('-ignore -ssl-errors')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Add the cookies
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    with open('cookies.json') as f_cookies:
        cookies_list = json.load(f_cookies)
    for cookie in cookies_list:
        cookie_dict = {
            "domain": cookie['domain'],
            'name': cookie['name'],
            'value': cookie['value'],
            "expires": "",
            'path': '/',
            'httpOnly': True,
            'HostOnly': False,
            'Secure': False}
        driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict)

    driver.get(
        'https://ads.google.com/aw/keywordplanner/home?ocid=914430876&euid=626143847&__u=8483461103&uscid=914430876&__c=7080993724&authuser=1&subid=hk-en-et-g-aw-c-home-awhp_xin1_signin%21o2-awhp-hv-01-22')

    # click find new keyword
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5).until(
        lambda el: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "collapsed-content")]'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "collapsed-content")]').click()

    # input keyword
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5).until(
        lambda el: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "input-container _ngcontent")]/input'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "input-container _ngcontent")]/input').send_keys(keyword)

    # get_result
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5).until(
        lambda el: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "submit-button-container")]/material-button'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "submit-button-container")]/material-button').click()

    # click download
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5).until(
        lambda el: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "right-container _ngcontent")]'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "right-container _ngcontent")]').click()

    # download csv
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.5).until(lambda el: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                                        '//div[contains(@class, "group menu-container-group")]/material-select-item'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "group menu-container-group")]/material-select-item').click()

    # check download
    while True:
        if 'Downloading report' in driver.page_source:
            while True:
                if 'Downloading report ' not in driver.page_source:
                    break
                time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_keyword('iphone')
```

cookies.json:

```
[
{
    "name": "__Secure-1PAPISID",
    "value": "nQuT2FnmvaOYc-vb/AT7g99MzJQnqfXfC7",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 1
},
{
    "name": "__Secure-1PSID",
    "value": "KQg35bZrOyDZABSeXxgel927eh95zEKeXv4ldFLD04hkyno_5X692B5nWzELt0IS5wrdqg.",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 2
},
{
    "name": "__Secure-3PAPISID",
    "value": "nQuT2FnmvaOYc-vb/AT7g99MzJQnqfXfC7",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 3
},
{
    "name": "__Secure-3PSID",
    "value": "KQg35bZrOyDZABSeXxgel927eh95zEKeXv4ldFLD04hkyno_RgZMv9UyFRGNfdrJKsmaeA.",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 4
},
{
    "name": "__Secure-3PSIDCC",
    "value": "AJi4QfFnXJVIktuONOtwvU_wxzkBocjUfBjnrCrCOODYWw1_n2nlJfsRF8LMi1ezBamb99k1",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1684998894,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "name": "1P_JAR",
    "value": "2022-05-25-07",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1656054709,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 6
},
{
    "name": "AEC",
    "value": "AakniGOZjnZ1XGvPUEYZOY2h3uKV-fE0U4ehZ5jv9-B8mZxlvn3Ss_843NM",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "lax",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1669014708,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 7
},
{
    "name": "APISID",
    "value": "0rvoZN9OeyxTnlgg/Ash-_suP9SXKAPEAW",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 8
},
{
    "name": "HSID",
    "value": "A87GXCAkAZxMzSvXg",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 9
},
{
    "name": "NID",
    "value": "511=K2fZr9_k-3uX2X_06UEZPYoL_hLq9E9PTJkQtKxc_pddSHD7IcH92pYb0mvSUKwLygQJFCQHDYmNMmJgGH0vxUpgyqjBcwF1F67fX8JNZeJv3XBsY7QGt6FLuq8s8qW8jVhM6A3m95cNT6w2riTftWsYklSVwWPYVzHAx2ubZURPmNGHt50b73cAqiL3Veu554VszkI6hkykKbQFKqfMOX6qwGNjtkGQczajSW6yYrV7Dkix",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1669273908,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 10
},
{
    "name": "SAPISID",
    "value": "nQuT2FnmvaOYc-vb/AT7g99MzJQnqfXfC7",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 11
},
{
    "name": "SEARCH_SAMESITE",
    "value": "CgQIwZUB",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "strict",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1669014429,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 12
},
{
    "name": "SID",
    "value": "KQg35bZrOyDZABSeXxgel927eh95zEKeXv4ldFLD04hkyno_ngDuJhhjsM49eI5AS73uew.",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 13
},
{
    "name": "SIDCC",
    "value": "AJi4QfH040DHcYM7j6rPTqLYps3pnDkZXU5RObuPJFZ4sx6ot5nJDbvG2fXuFw1IHlJrZxk35g",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1684998894,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 14
},
{
    "name": "SSID",
    "value": "AGhhYX00aOTQefBzp",
    "domain": ".google.com",
    "hostOnly": false,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "session": false,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "partitionKey": null,
    "expirationDate": 1716534427,
    "storeId": "firefox-private",
    "id": 15
}
]
```

Comment: Also provide the webpage

Comment: I did what you asked me to do